# Is there a safe way to allow 3rd-party javascript in a page?

Tags: javascript

Is there a safe way in which untrusted javascript can be loaded into a page and trusted not to cause harm?

I would like to create an executable wiki containing user contributed javascript. But, I am concerned that malicious javascript could hijack the page and compromise the user's account on my system.

Are there workable ways to isolate javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Try [Google Caja](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/), which does exactly what (I think) you want.